# Separate project or separate jar?

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, project

I have a question related to the way I should be setting up the overall architecture of my project. I have a project A with a set of classes in it. Now project B also needs certain classes which are actually present in project A. There are two approaches that I am able to think of:

Approach 1: Create a separate project C with the classes which are common between project A and project B. Include project C as dependency in both project A and project B build path.

Approach 2: While building project A, build a separate jar including only the common classes. Once this jar is built, include this jar in the build path of project B.

Could you please help me understand which is of these approaches is more standard and follows the best practices of setting up projects?

Comment: I would go for approach 1.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks, could you please provide me a reason, I just want to  understand the reasoning behind this so that I am clear with the concepts :)

Comment: I agree, a three project structure (A, B and common) is a more flexible way of organizing the code. Also it makes it clear what is in each project. Convention over configuration is always preferred. (i.e. avoid special configuration of the A project build).

Comment: It is easier to maintain and to version. In this way, if only project A or B needs modifications to some of the classes, then you may have a specific branch for it until the changes need to be merged. Also, approach two looks more hard to implement.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza your comment makes complete sense to me now :) It would be good if I won't need to create a branch for project A if I just need to change the common classes. Thanks for your inputs.